# How to put 'geom_text' percent based on each bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

For example, I have a data frame as below with columns gender, year, count.

```
gender year count  
Man    2020 220     
Man    2019 206     
Man    2018 216     
Man    2017 156             
Woman  2020 45      
Woman  2019 47
```

Then I would like to put '%' on each stacked-bar with 100% per each bar in total. I tried but what I can get is separated % based on total bars.

[image]

For instance, on year 2020 I would like to have 'Man' with % of (220 / 220 + 45), and 'Woman' with (45 / 220 + 45).

This is the code I tired.

```
ggplot(data = all_gen, aes(x = year, y = count, fill = gender)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(count / sum(count) * 100, 1), "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.3, size = 4.5, col = "black") +
  labs(x = "", y = "Count", title = "Gender by year")
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the percentage for each year and then plot it using `ggplot2` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

all_gen %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(percentage = paste(round(prop.table(count) * 100, 2), '%')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = count, fill = gender, label = percentage)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
            hjust = 0.5, size = 4.5, col = "black") + 
  labs(x = "", y = "Count", title = "Gender by year")
```

[image]

Maybe changing Y-axis to percentage instead of count would be a better idea.

```
all_gen %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(percentage = round(prop.table(count) * 100, 2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = percentage, fill = gender, 
             label = paste0(percentage, '%'))) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
            hjust = 0.5, size = 4.5, col = "black") + 
  labs(x = "", y = "Percentage", title = "Gender by year")
```

[image]